# How to use disabledDate in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I wanto to disabled all the dates after a date that a person choose, so I call a function who is doing

```
$( "#final_date" ).datepicker({ datesDisabled: ['+m'] });
```

And my datepicker is like that

```
  activeDate() {
$("#initial_date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  startView: "days",
  minViewMode: "days",
  language: 'pt-BR'
});
$("#final_date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  startView: "days",
  minViewMode: "days",
  language: 'pt-BR',
  datesDisabled: this.disabledDates
});
```

}

But only one day after my date is being disabled, what am I doing wrong?????

Comment: Are you expecting this `['+m']` to be a string, a date, or a _moment_ object?  Note the [bootstrap datepicker documentation for `disabledDates()`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#endisableddates) says that `disabledDates`  _Takes an [ string or Date or moment ] of values and disallows the user to select those days._.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the goal is to

> disable *all* dates after a date

[The bootstrap datepicker documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#maxdate) says you can do this with `maxDate`.

> Takes a maxDate string, Date, moment, boolean:false parameter and disallows the user to select a moment that **is after that** moment. If a boolean:false value is passed options.maxDate is cleared and there is no restriction to the maximum moment the user can select. *[emphasis mine]*

Try this (while passing in your value for final_date):

```
final_date = '2019-11-11';
$( "#final_date" ).datepicker({ maxDate: final_date });
```